# Setting public IP using CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I am using a YAML file in the CloudFormation service on AWS. This file creates an EC2 server with a public IP and a stack output within the CloudFormation using the IP of the EC2 server that it just created. The output however, is not something we use a lot. Therefore I would like to close the server from time to time and open it again whenever I need it. The problem is that every time I launch the EC2 server again, it changes its public IP and the IP of the stack output doesn't change with it.

I found a way to make it static, using an elastic IP address from the EC2 service. However, I can't seem to find a way to select that IP address when choosing properties in creating the stack. So I would like some assistance on this.

Comment: If you don't actually want to pick your own IP address (ie, `1.2.3.4`), then you can associate an Elastic IP with an instance ID; see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/quickref-ec2.html#scenario-ec2-eip. The easiest way to do this is create the Elastic IP and EC2 instance in the same stack.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot define the IP address yourself, but you can extract it after it has been generated.

In your Cloudformation template, add an `Outputs` section like the following:

```
Outputs:
    myEc2IP: # just some identifier
        Value: !GetAtt myInstance.PublicIp # assuming that "myInstance" is your resource
```

Then, after deploying your stack, you can use the AWS CLI to extract the value:

```
aws cloudformation describe-stacks --stack-name $YOUR_STACK \
    --query 'Stacks[0].Outputs[?OutputKey==`myEc2IP`].OutputValue' \
    --output text
```

You can even load this into a shell variable by something like

```
export MY_ROLE_ARN="$(aws cloudformation describe-stacks …)"
```

Learn more about Outputs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/outputs-section-structure.html

See other possible output/return values for EC2 instances in Cloudformation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-instance.html (in the “Return values” section).

Answer (score 0):

> I can't seem to find a way to select that IP address when choosing properties in creating the stack. So I would like some assistance on this.

You can't select the IP address that you will get. [Elastic IP addresses](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/elastic-ip-addresses-eip.html) are chosen from Amazon's pool of IP addresses.

If you want to specify a specific IP address that you own, you can use [Bring your own IP addresses (BYOIP) in Amazon EC2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-byoip.html). That will allow you to specify the IP that you own to be used by your EC2 instances.